# Reading list: Housing Economics

Tags: reference-request

Hi Im looking for some books or articles or books on the basics of housing economics.

Where should I start?

Comment: How basic? High school? Undergraduate? College? Graduate? With a focus on models? Empirical data? Legal and regulatory regimes? Just housing or including housing finance?

Comment: Undergraduate would be good. I need a primer

Answer (score 1):

Alex Schwartz's "Housing Policy in the United States"
https://www.amazon.com/s?k=housing+economics&i=stripbooks&ref=nb_sb_noss

https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_there_any_classic_theory_or_book_for_housing_policy_and_housing_market

Lund Brian ' Understanding Housing Policy' 2017

Housing Economics
1st Edition
Authors: George Fallis
https://www.elsevier.com/books/housing-economics/fallis/978-0-409-82940-2

Housing and Mortgage Markets in Historical Perspective (National Bureau of Economic Research Conference Report)
by Eugene N. White, Kenneth Snowden, et al.

That's what I found.  Good Luck.  There are some forums that may have a better answer for you.